# DC analysis of double common source NMOS

Tags: amplifier

I have to calculate the \$R_1, R_2, R_{D_1}, R_{S_1} , R_{S_2} \$ resistors[image]

So i decided to calculate these resistance in the DC mode thus transforming the circuit in to the following : [image]

here comes my work : \$ \sqrt{\frac{I_{DQ_1}}{K_N}} + V_{TN} = V_{GSQ_1} = \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} (V^+ - V^-) - R_{S_1} \cdot I_{DS_{Q_1}}\$ and \$ (V^+ - V^-) - V_{DS_{Q_2}}= R_{S_2} \cdot I_{DQ_2}\$ and \$ \sqrt{\frac{I_{DQ_2}}{K_N}} + V_{TN} = V_{GSQ_2} = \frac{R_{S_1}}{R_{S_1}+R_{S_2}} (V^+ - V^-) - R_{S_2} \cdot I_{DS_{Q_2}}\$

Comment: For Q1 ok. But for Q2. How can Rs1 and Rs2 form a voltage divider? For Q2 we know Vds2 and Id2 thus Rs2 = (10V - 6V)/0.5mA = 8kΩ. Next we can solve for Vgs2 and from there we can find Rd1 and Rs1.

Comment: so Rs2 and Rs1 are in series or are they independent?

Comment: They are independent.

Comment: im really confused on how to find Rd1 and R1, R2 @G36 some hints please

Comment: The KVL is the answer. VRd1 = 10V - Vgs2 - V_RS2 = 10V - 2.781V - 4V = 3.22V

Comment: why did u work with the last branch instead ? isnt \$V_{Rd_1} = 10V - V_{DS_{Q_1}} - R_{S_1} I_{DS_{Q_1}} \$ @G36

Comment: Because we know Vgs2 and V_Rs2. And we do not know V_RS1 yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149009/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-g36).

Comment: @G36 can you please have a look at my last question in the discussion? thanks!